# How To Take Left Side String From A Particular position using PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, substring

I have a table in that table there is a column called eq1.sources in that column, entries are like mentioned below. Now I would like to extract the string from the left side to till card slot number only.

Example:

```
fdn:realm:pam:network:55.150.40.841:shelf-1:cardSlot-1:card:daughterCardSlot-1:daughterCard
```

for this entry I need only

```
fdn:realm:pam:network:55.150.40.841:shelf-1:cardSlot-1
```

similarly

```
fdn:realm:sam:network:35.250.40.834:shelf-1:cardSlot-1:card
```

for this entry I need

```
fdn:realm:sam:network:35.250.40.834:shelf-1:cardSlot-1
```

I have tried `substring(eq1.sources,0,position (':card:daughter' in eq1.sources))`. this is working only for row numbers 1,2,4,5,6,7,9,10 but row number 3,8,11 not working as the entries not continued with ':card:daughter'.

The column name for the below entries is eq1.sources.

```
1.fdn:realm:pam:network:55.150.40.841:shelf-1:cardSlot-1:card:daughterCardSlot-1:daughterCard
2.fdn:realm:pam:network:35.250.40.824:shelf-1:cardSlot-1:card:daughterCardSlot-1:daughterCard
3.fdn:realm:sam:network:35.250.40.834:shelf-1:cardSlot-1:card
4.fdn:realm:pam:network:55.159.40.994:shelf-1:cardSlot-2:card:daughterCardSlot-1:daughterCard
5.fdn:realm:pam:network:35.250.140.104:shelf-1:cardSlot-2:card:daughterCardSlot-1:daughterCard
6.fdn:realm:pam:network:55.170.40.1:shelf-1:cardSlot-2:card:daughterCardSlot-1:daughterCard
7.fdn:realm:pam:network:35.450.40.24:shelf-1:cardSlot-3:card:daughterCardSlot-1:daughterCard
8.fdn:realm:sam:network:35.250.40.14:shelf-1:cardSlot-3:card
9.fdn:realm:pam:network:55.150.40.854:shelf-1:cardSlot-4:card:daughterCardSlot-1:daughterCard
10.fdn:realm:pam:network:35.250.40.84:shelf-1:cardSlot-5:card:daughterCardSlot-1:daughterCard
11.fdn:realm:sam:network:35.250.40.84:shelf-1:cardSlot-6:card
```

Expecting a PostgreSQL query to extract left side substring from a particular position in a row.

Expected output is

```
1.fdn:realm:sam:network:35.250.40.834:shelf-1:cardSlot-1 
2.fdn:realm:sam:network:35.250.40.14:shelf-1:cardSlot-3:card
```

from

```
1.fdn:realm:sam:network:35.250.40.834:shelf-1:cardSlot-1:card:daughterCardSlot-1:daughterCard
2.fdn:realm:sam:network:35.250.40.14:shelf-1:cardSlot-3:card
```

Answer (score 0):

First split the string into an array with `:` as a delimiter (this is the `t` subquery) and then pick the first 7 array elements and join them again into a string with `:` delimiter.

```sql
select array_to_string(arr[1:7], ':') as sources
from
(
 select string_to_array(sources, ':') as arr 
 from the_table
) as t;
```

See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i37rEtf4uBaQAivjcfmVbR/1).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response and resolution Stefanov..Its working ....

Comment: Currently entries are in table like as mentioned above. For those entries the given formula  is working fine, hence, yes I accept the answer Stefanov...If there are any changes of entries in table then we shall try to change the formulas accordingly. Thanks again Stefanov.